# Plesk password for MySql database on Windows 2008 IIS

Tags: php, mysql, iis, windows-server-2008, plesk

I have Plesk 11 installed on a Windows 2008 server.

I would like to create websites without having to use Plesk.

However, I cannot logon to the MySql database that is also installed.  It appears Plesk has changed the logon credentials of root and admin.  The password is not the same as the password to logon to the plesk control panel.

Does anyone know how to find out what the new password is?

Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another user with admin's privileges (all global privileges), just open phpMyADmin  for MySQL Database server in Tools & Settings > Database Servers. Than in phpMyAdmin > Users > Create User > select all privileges.

If phpMyAdmin is not installed you can install it in "Updates and Upgrades":

[image]

Comment: Hi - I need to know the login before I can get phpMyAdmin to connect to the MySql database though.  Or have I missed the point?  Thank you, Mark

Comment: No, you don't need to know login and password, because Plesk creates auth session in phpMyAdmin, so you just need to click an icon of database webadmin.

Comment: Hi - phpMyAdmin wasn't installed by Plesk - no database admin was - so I would have to install it myself - but still need to know the admin logon details that plesk used to create the MySql database.  Thank you, Mark

Comment: You can install it in "Updates and Upgrades" > "Add components" > choose phpMyAdmin

Comment: Thank you - phpMyAdmin wasn't listed in there - however I did create a new user from the plesk interface, and used MySql Workbench on the server to access it.  Thanks for all your help.  Mark